# SQL querying for segment positive values and negative and sum the value for distinct name

Tags: sql

[image: Here is the question below]

My querying is as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, money CASE
         WHEN [money] < 0 THEN SUM(money) GROUP BY name
       END AS "sum_of_withdraws"
       CASE
         WHEN [money] >= 0 THEN SUM(money) GROUP BY name
       END AS "sum_of_deposits"
FROM table
```

Can anyone show a correct querying or improve my querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this query...

```
SELECT 
    [name],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [money] >=0   THEN [Money] else 0 END)    sum_of_deposits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [money] <0    THEN [Money] else 0 END)*-1 sum_of_withdrawals
FROM 
    transfers
GROUP BY 
    [name]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [money] < 0 THEN money
           END) AS sum_of_withdraws,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [money] >= 0 THEN money
           END) AS "sum_of_withdraws"
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

The `CASE` expression is an argument to `SUM()`.  And `GROUP BY` is an entirely separate clause that follows `FROM`.